# Getting Video file path from uri

Tags: java, performance, android

I am using below code to get a video file path from uri.

Need review for the following:

1.Code optimization

2.Crash(Code is working fine in the devices I tested but i need to make sure that it doesn't crashes in any case)

3.Performance

4.Overall code review

```
 /**
     * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
     * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
     * other file-based ContentProviders.
     */
    private String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

            // ExternalStorageProvider

            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                } else {
                    // Below logic is how External Storage provider build URI for documents
                    // Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605278/android-5-sd-card-label and https://gist.github.com/prasad321/9852037
                    StorageManager mStorageManager = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);

                    try {
                        Class<?> storageVolumeClazz = Class.forName("android.os.storage.StorageVolume");
                        Method getVolumeList = mStorageManager.getClass().getMethod("getVolumeList");
                        Method getUuid = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("getUuid");
                        Method getState = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("getState");
                        Method getPath = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("getPath");
                        Method isPrimary = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("isPrimary");
                        Method isEmulated = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("isEmulated");

                        Object result = getVolumeList.invoke(mStorageManager);

                        final int length = Array.getLength(result);
                        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                            Object storageVolumeElement = Array.get(result, i);
                            //String uuid = (String) getUuid.invoke(storageVolumeElement);

                            final boolean mounted = Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(getState.invoke(storageVolumeElement))
                                    || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(getState.invoke(storageVolumeElement));

                            //if the media is not mounted, we need not get the volume details
                            if (!mounted) continue;

                            //Primary storage is already handled.
                            if ((Boolean) isPrimary.invoke(storageVolumeElement) && (Boolean) isEmulated.invoke(storageVolumeElement))
                                continue;

                            String uuid = (String) getUuid.invoke(storageVolumeElement);

                            if (uuid != null && uuid.equals(type)) {
                                String res = getPath.invoke(storageVolumeElement) + "/" + split[1];
                                return res;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                }
            }


            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                    if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                        return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                    }
                }
                String[] contentUriPrefixesToTry = new String[]{
                        "content://downloads/public_downloads",
                        "content://downloads/my_downloads",
                        "content://downloads/all_downloads"
                };

                for (String contentUriPrefix : contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
                    Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix), Long.valueOf(id));
                    try {
                        String path = getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                        if (path != null) {
                            return path;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                }

                return null;
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

//            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri.
     */
    private String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                 String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    private boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    private boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    private boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean _crash_?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ to make sure code will not crash,,,

Comment: The getPath() function is overly large, decompose it into smaller private functions, I would do this at each if statement.